# Mean hitting times and monotone convergence theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Take the random walk on $\mathbb{N}= \{0,1,2, \ldots\}$ which starts at $x$ and jumps to the right with probability $p$ and to the left with probability $1-p=q$.  Let $T_p$ denote the first hitting time of $0$.  It's possible to compute $$\mathbb{E}_x[T_p] = \frac{x}{q-p}$$ directly, and it's also possible to argue that $\mathbb{E}_x[T_p] = \infty$ for $p \geq \frac{1}{2}$.  Since $T_p \geq 0$ and $T_p \leq T_{p'}$ for $p \leq p'$, I wanted to use the monotone convergence theorem applied to the result for $p < \frac{1}{2}$ to conclude $$\mathbb{E}_x[T_{\frac{1}{2}}] = \lim_{p \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}} \mathbb{E}_x[T_p] = \infty$$ except I'm not quite sure that these random variables are defined on the same measure space.  Is there some way to work with all $p$ at once so that I can apply the monotone convergence theorem?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The big problem here is the sentence $T_p \leq T_{p'}$; even if I placed a whole bunch of random walks on the same probability space, this sentence wouldn't make sense, and you wouldn't be able to apply MCT.

Comment: You're right about that - I'm hoping for a coupling similar to the standard one for percolation, e.g. http://everything2.com/title/proof+using+coupling+that+the+site+percolation+probability+function+is+monotone

Comment: @ABlumenthal And yet it does (make perfect sense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just take i.i.d. random variables $X_0$, $X_1$, $\dots$, each uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$, and then let the $p$-probability random walk jump right at time $i$ iff $X_i<p$.